# Spark not loading all the files from folder

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, apache-spark-2.0

I am trying to load multiple JSON files from a folder and each file ends with a number, so I am using the wild card (*) in the path, so that spark will read one by one.

spark skipping few files and not loading all the files.

Files I've in my folder

[image]

```
raw_assignments = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json(r"Assignments_*.json")

assignments_df_all = raw_assignments.select("*").withColumn("page",input_file_name()).createOrReplaceTempView("check_files")

spark.sql("select distinct substring(page,90)  from check_files").show()
```

getting below output

```
+-------------------------------+
|substring(page, 85, 2147483647)|
+-------------------------------+
|             Assignments_6.json|
|            Assignments_24.json|
|             Assignments_5.json|
|            Assignments_14.json|
|            Assignments_17.json|
|             Assignments_9.json|
|            Assignments_13.json|
|             Assignments_1.json|
|             Assignments_7.json|
|             Assignments_8.json|
|            Assignments_23.json|
+-------------------------------+
```

I am not understanding why spark skipping files, I've loaded each file manually to find if any of those files are corrupted and all the files are valid files.

Comment: What happens if you simply do `raw_assignments.select(input_file_name()).distinct().show(truncate=False)`?

Comment: I tried that @mazaneicha  and i'm still getting the same results,in fact, I loaded the data in the hive where the filename  an extra column, still not seeing all the files in the hive table

Comment: FYI , I am running spark on Unix